# Handling Oracle Procedures returning nested table types in Java

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I am using Java to invoke Oracle procedures and some these procedures have their OUT parameters as nested table types.
I need to then process the data in the nested table types and even their metadata (attributes of nested table) are required for processing.

```
OracleCallableStatement stmt = null;
//Build the call here
StringBuilder call = new StringBuilder("{call ");
call.append(procName);
call.append("}");

System.out.println(call.toString());

conn = _motifUserDataSource.getConnection();
System.out.println("PREPARING : "+call.toString());
stmt = (OracleCallableStatement)conn.prepareCall(call.toString());
// The return parameter is an ARRAY type (nested table)
stmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.ARRAY, "TABLE_NTT");
stmt.execute();

// Get the return value and covert it into a JDBC ResultSet
ARRAY array = (ARRAY) ((OracleCallableStatement)stmt).getOracleObject(1);
rs=array.getResultSet();

ResultSetMetaData metadata = rs.getMetaData();
```

**Problem:**
When I try the above code, I get the following error

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported feature: getMetaData
at oracle.jdbc.driver.ArrayDataResultSet.getMetaData(ArrayDataResultSet.java:1013)
at com.Testdb.execCheckRefCursorData
```

I need this metadata to identify the attributes/column names which is required during the processing stage.

Any inputs on how I can handle nested table type OUT parameters and extract both the data and metadata information from them using Resultset?